# When using the frame skipping wrapper for OpenAI Gym, what is the purpose of the np.max line?

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, wrapper, openai-gym, openai-api

I'm implementing the following wrapper used commonly in OpenAI's Gym for Frame Skipping. It can be found in dqn/atari_wrappers.py

I'm very confused about the following line:

```
max_frame = np.max(np.stack(self._obs_buffer), axis=0)
```

I have added comments throughout the code for the parts I understand and to aid anyone who may be able to help.

`np.stack(self._obs_buffer)` stacks the two states in `_obs_buffer`.

`np.max` returns the maximum along axis 0.

But what I don't understand is why we're doing this or what it's really doing.

```py
class MaxAndSkipEnv(gym.Wrapper):
    """Return only every 4th frame"""
    def __init__(self, env=None, skip=4):
        super(MaxAndSkipEnv, self).__init__(env)
        # Initialise a double ended queue that can store a maximum of two states
        self._obs_buffer = deque(maxlen=2)
        # _skip = 4
        self._skip       = skip

    def _step(self, action):
        total_reward = 0.0
        done = None
        for _ in range(self._skip):
            # Take a step 
            obs, reward, done, info = self.env.step(action)
            # Append the new state to the double ended queue buffer 
            self._obs_buffer.append(obs)
            # Update the total reward by summing the (reward obtained from the step taken) + (the current 
            # total reward)
            total_reward += reward
            # If the game ends, break the for loop 
            if done:
                break

        max_frame = np.max(np.stack(self._obs_buffer), axis=0)

        return max_frame, total_reward, done, info
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the `for` loop the `self._obs_buffer` holds the last two frames.
Those two frames are then max-pooled over, resulting in an observation, that contains some temporal information.